# C++ Segmentation fault at return statement when calling a RPC function

Tags: c++, c++11, rpc

When I call the rpc function on the client and send a integer as a argument, the function on the server should convert the integer to a symbolic adress. When calling the RPC function with callrpc, the integer is sent to the server, the server receives it, converts it to a symbolic address, but on the return statement I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the server code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <rpc/types.h>
#include <rpc/xdr.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <netdb.h>

char *from_number_to_symbolic(int number) {

        struct sockaddr_in temp = { AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, { number } };
        static char symbolic[100]; 

        getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &temp, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), symbolic, 100, NULL, 0, 0);
        std::cout << std::endl << symbolic << std::endl;
        return symbolic;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        registerrpc(42700, 1, 1,(char* (*)(char *)) from_number_to_symbolic, (xdrproc_t) xdr_int, (xdrproc_t) xdr_wrapstring);

        svc_run();
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int from_numeric_to_int(char *numeric) {
        struct in_addr number;
        inet_pton(AF_INET, numeric, &number);

        return number.s_addr;
}

 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    char **num_adrress = &argv[1];
    int *int_adrress = new int;

    *int_adrress = from_numeric_to_int(*num_adrress);
    char **symbolic = new char*;
   
    callrpc("127.0.0.1", 42700, 1, 1, (xdrproc_t) xdr_int, (char *)num_adrress, (xdrproc_t) xdr_wrapstring, symbolic);

    std::cout << *symbolic << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run the server and the client like this: `./server`, `./client 64.233.166.94`. The server prints `208-107-167-85-dynamic.midco.net` which is the result I'm expecting but when the server tries to return it throws an segmentation fault.

Comment: **Never** edit out `#include` directives from code you post here.

Comment: The first argument is in `argv[1]`. You're effectively getting `argv[argc]` which is defined to be a null pointer.

Comment: And what RPC framework are you using? What is `int_adrress ` used for?

Comment: The argv[2] was a mistake when I was writing the question. RPC framework is tirpc. The int_adrress is converting the numeric IP address to an integer.

Comment: The explicit cast of `num_addrress` from `char **` to `char *` is very suspicious, since those two types aren't convertible in any useful manner.  Perhaps you want to pass `*num_address` instead of `(char *)num_address`, in the call to `callrpc()` ?

Comment: Still the same, in both cases the server receives the integer, converts it to a symbolic address but then fails to return it.

Comment: The address spaces for client and server programs are not the same. Unless this is running on a very simple computer, without an MMU or virtual process memory, what you seem to be trying to do won't work.

Comment: It is running on local host on a Linux Mint VM. I did a similar program sends a string and receives a integer and it works without problems.

Comment: `from_number_to_symbolic` is wrong, it should receive an address of `int` and return an address of an address of a string (so `char**`). All xdrproc functions work this way.

Comment: Don't rewrite code for your questions. Copy-paste the actual code for your [mre].

Answer (score 0):

There is some anti-idiomatic C++ and wrong usage of RPC API in the code. Here is a cleaned-up version:

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <rpc/svc.h>
#include <rpc/xdr.h>

char *from_number_to_symbolic(char* number_arg) {

  int number = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(number_arg); // <- fixed API usage

  sockaddr_in temp = {AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,
                      {static_cast<in_addr_t>(number)}, {}};
  static char symbolic[100];
  static char *symbolic_ret = symbolic;              // <- fixed API usage

  getnameinfo(reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&temp), sizeof(sockaddr_in),
              symbolic, 100, nullptr, 0, 0);
  std::cout << std::endl << symbolic << std::endl;
  return reinterpret_cast<char*>(&symbolic_ret);     // <- fixed API usage
}

int main()
{
  registerrpc(42700, 1, 1, from_number_to_symbolic, 
              reinterpret_cast<xdrproc_t>(xdr_int), 
              reinterpret_cast<xdrproc_t>(xdr_wrapstring));
  svc_run();
  return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int from_numeric_to_int(char* numeric) {
  struct in_addr number;
  inet_pton(AF_INET, numeric, &number);

  return number.s_addr;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc != 2)
  {
      exit(1);
  }

  int int_adrress = from_numeric_to_int(argv[1]);
  char* symbolic = nullptr; // <- no need to allocate on the heap

  auto ret = callrpc("127.0.0.1", 42700, 1, 1, 
                     reinterpret_cast<xdrproc_t>(xdr_int), 
                     reinterpret_cast<char*>(&int_adrress), 
                     reinterpret_cast<xdrproc_t>(xdr_wrapstring), 
                     reinterpret_cast<char*>(&symbolic));
  clnt_perrno(static_cast<clnt_stat>(ret));

  std::cout << symbolic << std::endl;

  xdr_free(reinterpret_cast<xdrproc_t>(xdr_wrapstring), 
           &symbolic); // <-- memory leak fix

  return 0;
}
```